# Closed map on Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces and $T \in B(X,Y)$. Show that if $T$ sends every bounded closed subsets of $X$ onto closed sets of $Y$ then $T(X)$ is closed.

It's true when the map is injective, but is it true in general?

Comment: What's your argument for injective $T$?

Comment: @tomasz would you mind going through the proof that $T(B)$ is closed for any closed, bounded $B$? The fact that $T(\ell_2)$ is not closed seems straightforward.

Comment: @tomasz This $T$ does not satisfy the assumption: Take the unit sphere (it is closed and bounded), $T(e_n)\to 0$, but $0$ is not in the image of the unit sphere under $T$.

Comment: Here is the proof for injective $T$:

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183146/bounded-linear-operator-maps-norm-bounded-closed-sets-to-closed-sets-implies-c

Comment: $S:=\{x\in l^2: \|x\|=1\}$, $0\in \overline{(T(S))}$, $0\not\in T(S)$, $S$ is closed and bounded, but $T(S)$ is not closed.

Comment: @daw: Oh, I was confusing the sphere with a ball. You're right. $T$ maps closed *balls* to closed sets, but not arbitrary closed sets.

Answer (score 3):

Given the answer here [Bounded linear operator maps norm-bounded, closed sets to closed sets. Implies closed range?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/183146/bounded-linear-operator-maps-norm-bounded-closed-sets-to-closed-sets-implies-c), 
the claim is true for injective $T$.

Now let $T$ be arbitrary. We work in the quotient space $X/N(T)$. 
For $x\in X$ let
$$
[x] = x + N(T) \in X/N(T).
$$
The quotient space is a Banach space under the norm
$$
\|[x]\|_{X/N(T)}:=\inf_{y\in N(T)}\|x-y\|_X.
$$
Define
$\hat T: X/N(T)\to Y$ by
$$
\hat T([x]) = Tx.
$$
Then $\hat T$ is injective, moreover $R(T)=R(\hat T)$. It remains to prove that $\hat T$ maps bounded and closed sets to closed sets.

Let now $M\subset X/N(T)$ be closed and bounded, $[z_n] \in M$ be given with $\hat T[z_n]\to y$. Since $M$ is bounded, we can choose $z_n\in [z_n]$ such that $Z:=\{z_n,\ n\in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded in $X$. 
By construction $Tz_n \to y$, thus 
$y\in cl(T(Z))$, and the assumption on $T$ implies $y\in T(cl(Z))$. Thus, there is a sequence $\tilde z_n\in Z$ with $\tilde z_n \to z\in cl(Z)$ and $Tz=u$. Now, $\tilde z_n\to z$ implies $[\tilde z_n]\to [z]$ in $X/N(T)$. Since $[\tilde z_n]\in M$ this implies $[z]\in M$ and $\hat T[z]=u$.